# Control percentage of non-interesting questions on home page

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, homepage

I really like the selection of questions on the home page. But I also think at times it could do with more questions that don't falled into my interesting tags, since that's the way I tend to discover new interesting tags.

How about letting the user define what percentage of questions displayed should be from interesting tags? That way those who want to hide everything else can do so, while people like me who'd like say 30% from non-interesting tags can get there way too?

Comment: what is *the home page*? Stack Overflow? Or are you referring to any Stack Exchange site?

Comment: @Peter http://stackoverflow.com